# python SSH to diffrent hosts with parallel-SSH

Tags: python, ssh, parallel-processing

With parallel-SSH python library is the actual SSH-ing done in parallel for different hosts, or just running other commands in hosts is done in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

"pssh is a pretty good tool for parallel SSH command execution on many servers. It quite is useful if you have 5 or 7 servers or VMs. Nevertheless, if you need to do something complicated you should look into Ansible and co. See the official site here for more info."

https://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/how-to-use-pssh-parallel-ssh-program-on-linux-unix/

Comment: What is the issue that pssh would ran into, if you have lets say 50 servers?